# Can't able to locate Web Element using xpath

Tags: xpath, automated-tests

I want to click on `+` icon, which state name is having attribute as `data-stateid=1`,

But when I try to find web element using `firepath`.
 
All `+` icon is having the same attribute as `class` so, I'm not able to click on specific `+` icon.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
 <h4 class="panel-title">
  <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#lob1" data-stateid="1">
   <span class="tag tag-default tag-pill pull-xs-right">0</span>
    <i class="fa fa-plus pull-xs-right btn-country-list" onclick="GetLobPopUp('AL','Alabama')"/>
 </h4>
</div>
<div id="lob1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" style="height: auto;">
 <div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
   <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#lob3" data-stateid="3">
    <span class="tag tag-default tag-pill pull-xs-right">0</span>
     <i class="fa fa-plus pull-xs-right btn-country-list" onclick="GetLobPopUp('AZ','Arizona')"/>
 </h4>
</div>
<div id="lob3" class="panel-collapse collapse in" style="height: auto;">
 <div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
   <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#lob4" data-stateid="4">
    <span class="tag tag-default tag-pill pull-xs-right">0</span>
     <i class="fa fa-plus pull-xs-right btn-country-list" onclick="GetLobPopUp('AR','Arkansas')"/>
  </h4>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me on this issue?
Best Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is identify the element first with using different attributes.. if you can't use `class`, then use `data-stateid`:

`//a[@data-stateid='1']/following-sibling::i`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this query:

```
//h4[./a[@data-stateid=1]]/i
```

(tested on http://xpather.com/9pCZr2I0)

*The pasted HTML seems a bit malformed so I corrected it.*

Comment: Reason behind down vote as, i want to click on data-state id =1 and you provided the data-state id =3, which is not valid and not required for me.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I missed that you wanted stateid=1 exactly but I think correcting it was not too much effort and down voting was not necessary. I corrected it already!

Comment: Update as up-vote. :) Now it is as per requirement and behaving correctly.